# Mongo compound index with geo location not working

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, indexing, compound-index

I am having hard time with something that supposed to be trivial....
I have the following profile document structure:

```
 {
   pid:"profileId",
   loc : {
       "lat" : 32.082156661684621,
       "lon" : 34.813229013156551,
       "locTime" : NumberLong(0)
         }
   age:29
 }
```

A common use-case in my app is to retrieve nearby profiles filtered by age.

```
   { "loc" : { "$near" : [ 32.08290052711715 , 34.80888522811172] , "$maxDistance" :    179.98560115190784}, "age" : { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 33}}
```

So I have created the following compound index:

```
  { 'loc':2d , age:1}
```

And no matter what I do I can't make the query run with the created index (also tried with hint)
this is the generated explain for the query:

```
  { 
  "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor" , 
  "isMultiKey" : false , 
  "n" : 4 , 
  "nscannedObjects" : 4 , 
  "nscanned" : 4 , 
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4 , 
  "nscannedAllPlans" : 4 , 
  "scanAndOrder" : false , 
  "indexOnly" : false , 
  "nYields" : 0 , 
  "nChunkSkips" : 0 , 
  "millis" : 0 , 
  "indexBounds" : { } ,
  "allPlans" : [ { "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor" , "n" : 4 , "nscannedObjects" : 4 , "nscanned" :    4 , "indexBounds" : { }
  }
```

I am using mongodb version 2.4.4.

What am I doing wrong? your answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you storing your index in {lat, long} order as suggested in your document structure? The [order for a 2d index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/) has to be {long, lat}. It would be helpful if you can include some sample points that you would expect to find in your $near query.

Comment: As you can see my loc embedded object including more properties then lat,long and the order is lat,lon.. do you think that will cause the use of the compound index?

Comment: As per the explain, the query **is** using a `GeoSearchCursor` (2d geospatial index). You need to have your coordinates in long, lat order or the geo query will not work as expected .. this is the only supported order for a 2d index.

Answer (score 6):

The explain output says "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor". This indicates your query used a geospatial index.

See the following for details:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

2d indexes support a compound index with only one additional field, as a suffix of the 2d index field.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes

As @stennie mentioned in the comment on your question the problem might be the ordering of the coordinates. They should be ordered long, lat. If that doesn't work try storing the loc as an array with long first element, lat second.

Here is a worked example:

I created three profile objects with location as array and the locTime separate from loc.

```
> db.profile.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52cd54f1c43bb3a468b9fd0d"), "loc" : [  -6,  50 ], "age" : 29, "pid" : "001", "locTime" : NumberLong(0) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52cd5507c43bb3a468b9fd0f"), "loc" : [  -6,  53 ], "age" : 30, "pid" : "002", "locTime" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52cd5515c43bb3a468b9fd10"), "loc" : [  -1,  51 ], "age" : 31, "pid" : "003", "loctime" : NumberLong(2) }
```

Finding using large distance and age

```
> db.profile.find({ "loc" : { "$near" : [ -1, 50] , "$maxDistance" : 5}, "age" : { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 33}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52cd5515c43bb3a468b9fd10"), "loc" : [  -1,  51 ], "age" : 31, "pid" : "003", "loctime" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52cd54f1c43bb3a468b9fd0d"), "loc" : [  -6,  50 ], "age" : 29, "pid" : "001", "locTime" : NumberLong(0) }
```

The explain shows the index is being used:

```
> db.profile.find({ "loc" : { "$near" : [ -1, 50] , "$maxDistance" : 5}, "age" : { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 33}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "nscanned" : 2,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
}
```

Narrow the distance with the same age range

```
> db.profile.find({ "loc" : { "$near" : [ -1, 50] , "$maxDistance" : 1}, "age" : { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 33}})
```

Here is the explain, again the index is used:

```
> db.profile.find({ "loc" : { "$near" : [ -1, 50] , "$maxDistance" :     1}, "age" : { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 33}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
}
```

Here are the indexes:

```
> db.profile.getIndices()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "test.profile",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "loc" : "2d",
            "age" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "test.profile",
        "name" : "loc_2d_age_1"
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that I can't use compound index with 2d ? the query using geospatial index cause I have 2d index on the loc field in my object... how can I use the compound index ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can use a compound index with 2d. 2d indexes support only one additional field, as a suffix of the 2d index field. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes